# show that $f$ is continuous if and only if $\tau'$ is finer than $\tau$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

let $A$ and $A'$ denote a single set in two topologies $\tau$  and $\tau '$ respectively on set $X$.

let $f:A'\to A$ be identity map.

show that $f$ is continuous if and only if $\tau'$ is finer than $\tau$.

let $U$ any open set in $(X,\tau)$

want to show $U$ is open in $(X,\tau')$ assuming $f$ is continous.

it mean $U\cap A$ is open in $(A,\tau_A)$ and hence $f^{-1}(U\cap A)=U\cap A\ $ is open in $(A',\tau_{A'})$

From this how will we show that $U$ is open in $(X,\tau')$

any hint??thanks in advanced

Comment: It is not true as stated. Assume that $X=A\cup B$ with $A,B$ open in both topologies. Let $\tau$ and $\tau'$ coincide on $A$. Then $f$ is continuous. But on $B$ the topologies could be anything, incomparable for example. You can show that the topologies on $A$ are one finer than the other, that form is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that your problem is this:

> Let $X$ be a set and consider on $X$ two topologies $\tau$ and $\tau'$. Let $f\colon(X,\tau')\longrightarrow(X,\tau)$ be the identity function. Show that $f$ is continuous if and only if $\tau'$ is finer than $\tau$.

If $f$ is continuous and $A$ is an element of $\tau$, then, by definition, $A$ is an open subset of $(X,\tau)$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(A)$ is an open subset of $(X,\tau')$. In other words, $A\in\tau'$. This proves that $\tau'$ is finer than $\tau$.

And if $\tau'$ is finer than $\tau$, then, if $A\in\tau$, $f^{-1}(A)(=A)\in\tau'$. Therefore, $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I still don’t understand why $\tau’ \supseteq\tau$. If anything, $\tau’ =\tau$ since, as I believe you showed, both topologies have a one to one correspondence. Everything else makes sense, though.

Comment: @majormaki I took an element $A\in\tau$ and then I proved that $A\in\tau'$. Doesn't this prove, from your point of view, that $\tau\subseteq\tau'$?

Comment: It does, but then why settle for such a weak result when there is a stronger one that requires only to change a symbol?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help and replying so quickly.

Comment: @majormaki Weak? It's the best we can get. Suppose that $X=\mathbb R$, that $\tau$ is the usual topology and that $\tau'$ is the discrete topology. Then $\tau\varsubsetneq\tau'$.

Comment: Oh, okay. I get it. Thanks again.